# Difficulties to update an ArrowHelper without allocate new one

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to update the components of 3 `ArrowHelper` with `three.js`. Right now, I can successfully make update the 3 `ArrowHelper` of my animation only by allocating new ones at each call of my drawing function.

For example, in my `main` function, I start by allocating 3 `ArrowHelper` like this :

```
// Parameters for vector
var directionMainVectorX = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
var directionMainVectorY = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var directionMainVectorZ = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

var originMainVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var lengthVector = 20;
var widthVector = 3;
var headLengthVector = 1.5;
var headWidthVector = 1.5;
var hexVector = 0x11ff00;

mainVectorX = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorX, originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
mainVectorY = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorY, originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
mainVectorZ = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorZ, originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
```

Then, into the `drawVector()` function, I have :

```
function drawVector() {

  // Parameters for ArrowHelper
  var headLengthVector = 1.5;
  var headWidthVector = 1.5;
  var hexVector = 0x11ff00;
  var widthVector = 3;

  // SOLUTION : Allocating each time a new vector
  mainVectorX = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorX.normalize(), originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorY = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorY.normalize(), originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorZ = new THREE.ArrowHelper(directionMainVectorZ.normalize(), originMainVector, lengthVector, hexVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
            
  // Width for mainVector
  mainVectorX.line.material.linewidth = widthVector;    
  mainVectorY.line.material.linewidth = widthVector;    
  mainVectorZ.line.material.linewidth = widthVector;    
    
  // Add arrows to scene reference
  scene.add(mainVectorX);
  scene.add(mainVectorY);
  scene.add(mainVectorZ);    

}
```

And finally, my `render` function :

```
function render() {

  rotateCamera();
  
  drawVector();

  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  scene.remove(mainVectorX);
  scene.remove(mainVectorY);
  scene.remove(mainVectorZ);

}
```

With all the code above, everything works fine.

My issue is that I would like not to use the "`allocating at each call of drawVector() function`".

That's why I start by allocating only one time the 3 `ArrowHelper` (I do it at the beginning of `main` code) and update their components by using into `drawVector()` function, like this:

```
function drawVector() {

  // Parameters for ArrowHelper
  var headLengthVector = 1.5;
  var headWidthVector = 1.5;
  var hexVector = 0x11ff00;
  var widthVector = 3;

  // Compute coordinates of 3vectors

  // Compute directions
  directionMainVectorX.set(1, 0, 0);
  directionMainVectorY.set(0, 1, 0);  
  directionMainVectorZ.set(0, 0, 1);    
  
  // Update mainVector
  
  // SOLUTION : update the parameters of vector
  mainVectorX.position.set(originMainVector);
  mainVectorY.position.set(originMainVector);
  mainVectorZ.position.set(originMainVector);    

  mainVectorX.setDirection(directionMainVectorX.normalize());
  mainVectorY.setDirection(directionMainVectorY.normalize());  
  mainVectorZ.setDirection(directionMainVectorZ.normalize());  

  mainVectorX.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorX.setColor(hexVector)
  
  mainVectorY.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorY.setColor(hexVector)
  
  mainVectorY.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorY.setColor(hexVector)    

  // Add arrows to scene reference
  scene.add(mainVectorX);
  scene.add(mainVectorY);
  scene.add(mainVectorZ);    
}
```

I saw this method on this previous post: [`update ArrowHelper`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554946/three-js-how-can-i-update-an-arrowhelper)

But unfortunately, nothing appears. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector3.set` takes 3 parameters - `x, y, z` not another vector
so you should use 
`mainVectorX.position.set(originMainVector.x,originMainVector.y,originMainVector.z);`

or `mainVectorX.position.copy(originMainVector);`

rewrite your drawVector (now it can be called updateVector :) ) as

```
function drawVector() {

  // Parameters for ArrowHelper
  var headLengthVector = 1.5;
  var headWidthVector = 1.5;
  var hexVector = 0x11ff00;
  var widthVector = 3;

  if(!mainVectorX.parent){    
    // Add transported arrow to scene reference
    scene.add(mainVectorX);
    scene.add(mainVectorY);
    scene.add(mainVectorZ);    
  }
  mainVectorX.position.copy(originMainVector);
  mainVectorY.position.copy(originMainVector);      
  mainVectorZ.position.copy(originMainVector);

  mainVectorX.setDirection(directionMainVectorX.normalize());
  mainVectorY.setDirection(directionMainVectorY.normalize());  
  mainVectorZ.setDirection(directionMainVectorZ.normalize());  

  mainVectorX.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorX.setColor(hexVector);

  mainVectorY.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorY.setColor(hexVector);

  mainVectorY.setLength(lengthVector, headLengthVector, headWidthVector);
  mainVectorY.setColor(hexVector);
}
```

and of course you should remove the

```
scene.remove(mainVectorX);
scene.remove(mainVectorY);
scene.remove(mainVectorZ);
```

from the render function